# React django permissions

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I am still new in react
when I tried to delete an element from API(django rest framework) in my case it's not working
Error message :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/delete/3' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVNr1.png)

Comment: You can try to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` to your React project's **package.json**

Comment: pip install django-cors-headers. install this package
https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ you visit this site for full documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-cors-headers 

#in settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]
```

Comment: thank you mr mehedi  for your comment its not working just for delete operation (create,read ,update)are all working

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I wasn't putting slash '.../' at the end of the
address.

```
deleteChat = async (id) => {
    let data = await api.delete(`/${id}/`)
}
```

Hopefully that helps.